# Saving Texture2D to file not working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, io, textures

So I've created this class based off of the Texture2D.EncodeToPNG code example on Unity's website. I'm not getting any errors when I execute it, but I'm also not seeing a new file created. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public class CreateJPG : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public int width = 1050;
    public int height = 700;

    string fileName;
    string filePath;
    // Texture2D tex;

    public void GrabJPG () {
        SaveJPG();
        Debug.Log("GrabJPG Executing");
    }

    IEnumerator SaveJPG()
    {   
        // We should only read the screen buffer after rendering is complete
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        // Create a texture the size of the screen, RGB24 format
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0,0,width,height),0,0);
        tex.Apply();

        // Encode texture into JPG
        byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToJPG(60);
        Object.Destroy(tex);

        // Get filePrefix from GameSetup array index
        GameObject init = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Initializer");
        GameSetup gameSetup = init.GetComponent<GameSetup>();
        string prefix = gameSetup.filePrefix;
        string subDir = gameSetup.subDir;

        string dtString = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_HHmmssfff");
        fileName = prefix+dtString+".jpg";
        filePath = "/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/"+subDir+"/";

        Debug.Log("SaveJPG Executing");

        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath+fileName, bytes);
        Debug.Log("Your file was saved at " + filePath+subDir+prefix+fileName);

        if(width > 0 && height > 0)
        {

        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: The directory exists? Get any exceptions?

Comment: It does exist and no I'm not getting any exceptions. It's weird, I'm just not seeing what's wrong.

Comment: Try to put your code in a try-catch from texture creation till last Debug.Log, print your exception message + trace in console.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't start your coroutine, you need to call [StartCodoutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) in GrabJPG:

```
StartCoroutine(SaveJPG());
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/scripting/coroutines

P. S. By the way, you can use [Application.CaptureScreenshot](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.CaptureScreenshot.html)